# What is the online URL of todo list manager app Astrid?

Tags: astrid

I often use both the [web version](http://astrid.com) & the [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.astrid) to manage my todo lists. But since Yahoo acquired Astrid, the web version doesn’t work anymore.

What is wrong with it? Where can I manipulate my todo(s) via a web browser?

**Update:** Now the Android app stopped working too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It got shut down, so you can’t access it anymore.

> First off, we want to sincerely thank you for being an Astrid user over the years. Your support every step of the way has meant the world to us. **As of August 5, 2013, we will be closing the Astrid service**.

(Emphasis by me.)

And they recommend exporting your tasks and start using a different app.

[Source](http://blog.astrid.com/blog/2013/07/08/astrid-winding-down/).

Answer (score 1):

It has already been shut down and we all have turned to other to-do app instead. Currently in the market, you have many choices. Some are even better than Astrid. I am using TickTick now and recommend you to have a try also. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ticktick.task